# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()'

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencv, centos8

I am trying to build my Java project with maven and opencv on Centos 8. With try some way to fix, i can build it as a `.jar` file to run API. But when my service call lib from opencv, it throws the following error: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat()'` .

My reference to install opencv in centos 8: https://my.oschina.net/u/3568600/blog/4553084 
This is my step:

1. Install cmake and ant.
2. Download: `wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.4.0.zip` and unzip it
3. Run command: `cd opencv`
    `mkdir build`
    `cd build`
4. Run cmake: `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF ..`
5. `make` 
   `sudo make install` 
   Outout after run this step:
   [image]

   Move lib: `cp -r /usr/local/share/java/opencv4/libopencv_java440.so /usr/lib`
6. Check version: `ldconfig -v | grep opencv`
   Here my ouput:
   [image]

---

Here my java code to load core native lib:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.load("/user/lib/libopencv_java440.so");
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
```

My process throw error:

```
    public static Mat BufferedImage2Mat(BufferedImage image) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", byteArrayOutputStream);
        byteArrayOutputStream.flush();
        return Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()), Imgcodecs.IMREAD_UNCHANGED); // Throw in this line
    }
```

What do you recommend I do next? 
***Note:*** my code running normal in local (Windows) with change `libopencv_java440.so` to `opencv_java440.dll` and add `opencv-440.jar` to class path in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I found simple way to resolve it.
In pom.xml add dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.opencv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencv-440</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.0</version>            
</dependency>
```

Register opencv-440.jar to maven by command:
`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/path/opencv-440.jar -DgroupId=org.opencv -DartifactId=opencv-440 -Dversion=4.4.0 -Dpackaging=jar`